# Could not open the database in read/write mode

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I'm trying to load a Database file from my SD card,but is giving exception.
Below is the exception

```
org.sqlite.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: not an error (code 0): Could not open the database in read/write mode.
```

And here is my code:

```
public void csr_test_1() throws Exception
```

{

```
DB_PATH=new File("/storage/sdcard1/sk2.db");
   SQLiteDatabase db = SQLiteDatabase.openOrCreateDatabase(DB_PATH, null);
   String res = "";


Cursor c = db.rawQuery("SELECT synsetid, w2.lemma FROM sense LEFT JOIN word AS w2 ON   w2.wordid=sense.wordid WHERE sense.synsetid IN (SELECT sense.synsetid FROM word AS w1 LEFT      JOIN sense ON w1.wordid=sense.wordid WHERE w1.lemma='"+ "life" + "') AND w2.lemma<>'" + "life" + "'", null);
if( c!=null ){
 boolean bRes;
 for(bRes=c.moveToFirst(); bRes; bRes=c.moveToNext()){
String x = c.getString(0);
res = res + "." + x;
}
}else{
}
test_result("csr_test_1.1", res, ".one.two.three");

db.close();
test_result("csr_test_1.2", db_is_encrypted(), "unencrypted");
}
```

These are the permission i'm using

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.EXPAND_STATUS_BAR" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.android.vending.BILLING" />

![enter image description here][1]
![enter image description here][2]
```

Please help me out... Thanks

[image: This is the path in sdcard]

Comment: Have you checked your permission to read/write external storage?

Comment: Have you added `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />` in your Manifest file

Comment: Hi crusader
I have added permission to my AndroidMainfest.xml
still its not working,It is working fine with emulator but when i run this in a device its show a exceptoion.

Comment: please post your logcat

Comment: there is high possibility the database doesnot exist in path you specified.. may be [this will help](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8957994/2345913)

Comment: The file do exist in the given path,please have a look of the image

Answer (score 3):

This exception is thrown if [`sqlite3_db_readonly()` returns non-zero](http://androidxref.com/4.4.2_r1/xref/frameworks/base/core/jni/android_database_SQLiteConnection.cpp#139). It can return non-zero if

- the database file is read-only, or
- the database file does not exist.

([Reference](https://sqlite.org/c3ref/db_readonly.html))

You have a hardcoded path `"/storage/sdcard1/sk2.db"` - it's likely a database does not exist there. Use variables from [`Environment`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html) to access your external storage instead of hardcoded paths.

Comment: Hi laalto It is working fine in emulator but when i run this in a device its show an exception.Database exist in that particular path

Comment: In the ddms file explorer screenshot, all user permissions are not set  : `----rwxr-x` instead of e.g. `-rwxrwxr-x`.

Answer (score 0):

add this permission to your `AndroidManifest.xml`.

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />`

Comment: I have added permission to my AndroidMainfest.xml
still its not working

Answer (score 0):

please use both  permission in manifest file

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Answer (score 0):

In case you still get this error even after you included:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

and you also implemented Runtime permissions then it almost certainly is a problem related to the way Android manages files from External SD Card. For more info check my answer here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/46383795/1502079

Answer (score 0):

if your sdk>N ,it must request write and read permission like this

```
ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
            new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
                    Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},
            1);
```

Comment: I think it's  sdk >= M (api 23)