# Not able to open database in read/write mode

Tags: android, android-sqlite

I am getting below error:

> not an error (code 0): Could not open the database in read/write mode.

I have added

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

I am trying to enter data in the database that is present in the SD card, I am able to read the data that is already present in the database through "OPEN_READONLY". I am getting error when using "OPEN_READWRITE"

Comment: Which Android version? Where on the SD card is the database? What code do you use to open the database? Is the SD card mounted read-write?

Comment: How we check if the SD card is mounted read/write?

Comment: The SD card entry in `/proc/mounts` has `rw` flag

Comment: It seems to me that you are using `getReadableDatabase()` instead of `getWritableDatabase()`

Comment: I am getting the same error. Did you find a solution for this ? My DB is in SD Card.

Answer (score 3):

Your question is not that clear, but I'll try to answer.

Most likely, your database either:

1. Don't exist yet, and you have to create it;
2. Your [database file is read only](https://sqlite.org/c3ref/db_readonly.html), you have to change it ([This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30082008/attempt-to-write-a-readonly-database-but-im-not) might be related).

For #2, instead of using [`SQLiteOpenHelper#getReadableDatabase()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper.html#getReadableDatabase()), use [`SQLiteOpenHelper#getWritableDatabase`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper.html#getWritableDatabase())

---

If your database is on an external storage unit, you have a few other things to check:

1. Is the external storage currently mounted? If not, you can't access the db.
2. Is it mounted as read only? If so, you'll have to change this.
3. Have you checked the path? Is it correct?

The problem might be on any of those topics.

To check if it's mounted as read-only, try the following:

```
/* Checks if external storage is available for read and write */
public boolean isExternalStorageWritable() {
    String state = Environment.getExternalStorageState();
    if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(state)) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

/* Checks if external storage is available to at least read */
public boolean isExternalStorageReadable() {
    String state = Environment.getExternalStorageState();
    if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(state) ||
        Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED_READ_ONLY.equals(state)) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Taken from [here](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/files.html).

For more info on the `Environment` class, please [refer to the docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html#MEDIA_MOUNTED_READ_ONLY).

Comment: I was able to read/write when my database was present in the internal storage of the phone.

Comment: So, you're trying to use a database on a SD card?

Comment: Yes, I am trying to use database that is present on a SD card

Comment: I am able to use the database present on SD card in OPEN_READONLY. Can you please tell me how to check if it is mounted as read only or read/write?

Comment: Edited the answer.

Comment: It is write capable.

Comment: Well... My first thought would be... Why don't you use it on the internal storage? Other thing I've noticed, you only need the write permission, try to remove the first one. And have you checked the database path? Is it correct?

Comment: I am not using internal storage because I am saving images as a blob too in the database. I have checked the path and it is correct as in the whole application I am able to retrieve data from the database in  OPEN_READONLY mode.

Comment: And I have checked isExternalStorageWritable() and it is returning true

Comment: @SakshiAgrawal - How did you solve the issue? I have the same issue and my db is in the SD card

Answer (score 1):

In Android API 4.3 and lower you can open databases in external SD Card, this code was working for read and write :

```
SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(DB_PATH, null,SQLiteDatabase.NO_LOCALIZED_COLLATORS);
```

Starting from API 4.4 you only can open databases in external SD Card READ_ONLY, you have to use this code :

```
SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(DB_PATH, null,SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);
```

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Answer for year 2022:
In case you are copying the database file after installing the app and see this error:

> not an error (code 0): Could not open the database in read/write mode.

Just try to copy the database file (via your pc or device explorer in Android Studio) while the app is up and running on the device (not when you exited).

Or alternatively set the folder permission as 777 by adb shell after the copying is finished.

Comment: Saved my day! For those not very familiar with adb. Run adb shell while having only one device connected. Then navigate to the database file and run: chmod 777 yourfile.sqlite

Answer (score 0):

With version *4.4 KitKat* some changes were introduced related to how Android handles storage and data security.

For example even if `isExternalStorageReadable()` will return true  you will not be able to write to External SD Card but only to the directory returned by `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()`.

```
/* Checks if external storage is available to at least read */
public boolean isExternalStorageReadable() {
    String state = Environment.getExternalStorageState();
    if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(state) ||
        Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED_READ_ONLY.equals(state)) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

To be able to delete, write, move files you have to use the **Storage Access Framework** which lets you access files located on your phone but also any remote files like for example files in Google Drive.

To open a database you have to provide a path but the Document Provider Api only lets you open an Input Stream or move files so in order to open a database you will have to move/copy the file to some *Private Internal storage* or to `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()` directory.

More info on this topic:

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/document-provider.html

https://stackoverflow.com/a/43317703/1502079

https://stackoverflow.com/a/21674485/1502079