# Move files to Download directory and view them on the device

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-emulator

Hello
I would like to move a file from cache directory to downloads. I have searched several hours for a solution but verified solutions which supposed to work also for me, unfortunately they did not. 
I have several files in cache and can read them without any problems. When trying copy them to download directory the action is working and I can see the file in adb shell but not on the device.
I do request permission from user using:

```
private static String[] PERMISSIONS_STORAGE = { android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, android.Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE };

ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(getActivity(), PERMISSIONS_STORAGE, 1);
```

[Download directory on the device](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8K9rR.png)
[Download directory on adb shell](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hfaCN.png)
My last try looks like this:

```
File source = new File(this.activity.getCacheDir(), "/" + item.getTitle());
File dest = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS), "/" + item.getTitle());
FileUtils.copy(new FileInputStream(source), dest);
```

AndroidManifest.xml contains also this lines:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Any help will be more then appreciate. Thanks!

Comment: a/ post your complete stacktrace b/ what android version your device is running? c/ do you request permission at runtime?

Comment: Look:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43066117/android-m-write-to-sd-card-permission-denied

Comment: I have edited the question. Thats my real problem. Sorry for the confusion.