# Use rn-fetch-blob with android Storage Access Framework

Tags: android, react-native, rn-fetch-blob

I am using `rn-fetch-blob` to download photos and want them to be stored in external sd card.
While I always get `'permission denied'` even I have set `android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` in `AndroidManifest.xml` and have ask permission request by `PermissionsAndroid.request` I still get the permission error.

After I searched on here and finally found the issue may be due to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43317703/10783924). However I don't know how to combine the `Storage Access Framework` with `rn-fetch-blob`.

So I would like to download photos by using `rn-fetch-blob` and stored them to sd card (path will like `/storage/6265-6530/DCIM/Camera/`)

Anyone help?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

As you did not provide any code for reference it is hard to see what is happening. Perhaps the problem is misspelling a character in the file path. To avoid this kind of thing you can use rn-fetch-blob [constants](https://github.com/joltup/rn-fetch-blob/wiki/File-System-Access-API#dirs). Another option is to use react-native-fs module, it offers a [constant](https://github.com/itinance/react-native-fs#constants) that maps to external storage.