# MuPDF save Document using Android SAF

Tags: android, mupdf, storage-access-framework

I am using mupdf library and I am deleting PDF Annotations and then saving the document using save method in PDFDocument.

```
Document doc = Document.openDocument(pdfFile.getAbsolutePath());
//I have code here to find the annotation at the touch location and delete it
((PDFDocument) doc).save(pdfFile.getAbsolutePath(), "");
```

Its working fine for the PDFs present in Phone Storage, but unfortunately Android doesn't support this method if pdfFile is in SD Card or in any removable storage. Hence I need to save it using storage access framework similar to here - https://stackoverflow.com/a/43317703

But PDFDocument doesn't have any method save the document to OutputStream  or any method which returns PDFDocument as stream.

Is there any possibility to save PDFDocument to SAF?

Comment: Save the PDF content to a file first (e.g., in `getCacheDir()`), then copy it to the location that you get via SAF.

Comment: Doing the same now. I am storing pdf to getFileDir() and copying it, but I am looking if there is any way to do it without copy as it will save the latency to copy file.