# Fatal Exception : unknown error (code 14) could not open database

Tags: android, android-sqlite, android-4.4-kitkat, sqliteopenhelper

My application is throwing this

```
Fatal Exception : unknown error (code 14) could not open database
```

when running on Android Kitkat 4.4,
The application is running perfectly on all the previous versions.

Exception is being thrown in this line.

```
            myDataBase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase("path", null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);
```

I have tried everything from 
SQLiteDatabase.create(); 
SQLiteDatabase.opendatabase(); SQLiteDatabase.openorcreatedatabase(null);
. But still the exception is being thrown in this line.

Comment: see this :

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7316191/android-sqlite-returned-error-code-14

and this :

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6202926/android-sqliteopenhelper-cannot-open-database-file

Comment: nope not working..first link is to set sharedUserID in manifest which i am not doing and other link does not have accepted answer

Answer (score 0):

If your variable `path` is a secondary external storage as a sdcard then you can not write data, how to create a db file sqlite . Android 4.4 prevented the writing of data at this location and manufacturers as Samsung has followed the same. The error message does not help to know what is really happening. See :

https://source.android.com/devices/storage/index.html#multiple-external-storage-devices